# add missing column to AWS Glue DataFrame

Tags: aws-glue, pyspark, aws-glue-spark

I am reading a DynamoDB Table with Glue, due to the dynamic schema it can happen that some columns are not existing.
Adding them works fine with the following code but I am not sure how to make the function dynamic if I need to add multiple columns.

```
# add missing columns if not available
def AddCustRegName(r):
    r["customerRegistrationName"] = ""  # add column with empty string.
    return r

if addCustRegName:
    case_df_final = Map.apply(frame=case_df_final, f=AddCustRegName)
```

Any suggestions?

The following code is failing with the below error

```
# add missing columns if not available
def AddColumn(r, col):
    r[col] = ""  # add column with empty string.
    return r

case_df_final = Map.apply(frame=case_df_final, f=AddColumn(case_df_final ,'accessoryTaxIncluded'))

case_df_final.toDF().printSchema()
```

> Fail to execute line 6: case_df_final = Map.apply(frame=case_df_final,
> f=AddColumn(case_df_final ,'accessoryTaxIncluded')) Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-4928209310219195923.py", line 375, in 
> exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)   File "", line 6, in    File "", line 3, in AddColumn TypeError:
> 'DynamicFrame' object does not support item assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you pass in [`Map`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-map.html) can have only one argument :

> `f` – The function to apply to all DynamicRecords in the DynamicFrame.
> The function must take a DynamicRecord as an argument and return a new
> DynamicRecord produced by the mapping (required).

However, you can do it on pyspark data frame instead of DynamicFrame :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def AddColumn(sdf, new_col):
    return sdf.withColumn(new_col, F.lit(""))

case_sdf_final = AddColumn(case_df_final.toDF(), "accessoryTaxIncluded")

case_sdf_final.printSchema()
```

Or if you have a list of columns to add you can use `functools.reduce` like this:

```
import functools

new_cols = ["customerRegistrationName", "accessoryTaxIncluded"]

case_sdf_final = functools.reduce(
    lambda acc, c: AddColumn(acc, c),
    new_cols,
    case_df_final.toDF()
)

case_sdf_final.printSchema()
```

Then go back to DynamicFrame:

```
case_df_final = DynamicFrame.fromDF(case_sdf_final, glueContext, "case_df_final")
```

Comment: Hey @blackbishop, I tired that approach but when I convert back to the DynamicFrame I am losing the columns again since they only contain empty strings. Any idea how can I avoid that?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I did something wrong in the variable assignment. Works as suggested!