# AWS Glue is not reading the blank columns

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a table in which few columns aree completetly blank, but when I read them using :

`glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "database", table_name = "table")`

the resulting dynamic frame does not have those columns, wheni printed the table schema using

`dF.printSchema()`

function. Is there any way to read all the null columns also without ignoring.

I have tried to use help of [`glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57718087/aws-glue-dropping-mostly-null-fields#comment101934959_57718087) but don't know how to use the same, as I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue with DynamicFrame.
This response is [addressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66102703/add-missing-column-to-aws-glue-dataframe) the issue.